# Why is $1-\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = 1-\frac{(n+2)-1}{(n+1)(n+2)}?$

Tags: polynomials, induction, factoring, fractions

This is a step during a mathematical induction inside a textbook example I don't get, why is

$1-\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)} = 1-\frac{(n+2)-1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$

Also, if anyone has some good online resources to practice this sort of stuff, I'd be eternally grateful!

Edit:

I added a picture of the textbook page. Hopefully that makes it a bit clearer, what I posted earlier was part of a mathematical induction, which may have caused some confusion.

[image: Here's the entire induction in paper format, I hope that clarifies things a little.]

Comment: Pls add proper brackets...

Comment: It’s improperly bracketed, as @Rohan notes. Worse than that, the LHS is clearly less than $2$ for large values of $n$, while the RHS is far larger than $2$ for large values of $n$. So the whole thing can’t be true unless you add a tremendous number of new parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because

$$1-{1\over n+1} + {1\over (n+1)(n+2)} \\
= 1-{n+2\over (n+1)(n+2)} + {1\over (n+1)(n+2)} \\
= 1-\left({n+2\over (n+1)(n+2)} - {1\over (n+1)(n+2)}\right) \\
= 1-\left({(n+2) - 1\over (n+1)(n+2)} \right) \\
= 1-{(n+2) - 1\over (n+1)(n+2)}  \\
  $$